# Account page - Showing account information

Tags: php, session, account

Hi I'm trying to write an account page that shows the information for the logged in user.  This is what I have so far:

```
 <?php
    include 'housestyle.php';
    include 'connection.php';
    global $mysqli;
    ?>
    <style>
    h1
    {

        font-size: 27px;
    }
    </style>

    <h1>Your Account</h1>
    <?php
    $profile=$_SESSION['userlogged'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=" . $profile . "";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print_r($row);
    }
    ?>
```

The $_SESSION['userlogged']; is from loginsubmit.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<font face="ClearSans-Thin">
<font color="lightgray">

    <?php
    include 'connection.php';
    include 'loginform.php';
    ?>
    <center>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        {
        $user = $_POST['username'];

        $pass = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Users WHERE Username='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user) . "' && Password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $pass). "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $queryadmin = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Admin WHERE Username='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user) . "' && Password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $pass). "'";
        $resultadmin = mysqli_query($connection, $queryadmin);
        $rowadmin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadmin);

        if ($row["cnt"] > 0) 
        {
            $_SESSION["userlogged"] =  $user;
            header("Location: homepage.php");
        } 
        else if ($rowadmin["cnt"] > 0 )
            {
                $_SESSION["adminlogged"] = $user;
                header("Location: homepage.php");
            }
        else 
        {
            echo 'Not a valid login';
        }
    }
    ?>
    </center>
```

So I'm trying to get it to identify the username that was entered on login and session start, then use it to return everything from that row. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: How is it going wrong? Are you getting an error? Are you getting a blank screen?

Comment: change your `$query` to `$query="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$profile'";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In upper script you don't do `session_start()`, so `$_SESSION` is empty.

Comment: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\account.php on line 5